# Is being a Reinhardt cardinal first-order definable?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

As is well known, Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but many of the proofs I've seen of this rely on combinatorial or club/stationary set properties.

If there's a (somewhat easy to see and **non-trivial**) first-order way of stating "$\kappa$ is Reinhardt", then we could easily appeal to elementarity to disprove their existence: the least Reinhardt $\kappa$ would have $V\models\text{“}\kappa\text{ is the least Reinhardt}\text{"}$ and so $V\models\text{“}j(\kappa)\text{ is the least Reinhardt}\text{"}$.

Does anyone know of such a definition, or are we more-or-less forced into the usual routes?

Comment: What you suggest is practically the simplest possible proof, and you might not know that, but a lot of very smart people work in set theory, and a lot of them at some point gave this some thought. Notice that your suggested proof doesn't even use choice! So just by appeal to authority this should hint that Reinhardt cardinals are not first order expressible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wasn't really trying to suggest the argument was new or something.  I just wasn't sure if maybe there were a such a definition, but it was rarely ever presented (maybe proving the equivalence takes too much time and space, or only holds in restricted circumstances etc.).  I suspected as much, but I just wanted to check :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not (well, "$0=1$" ... :P).

You're quite right that from a first-order definition of Reinhardt-ness, we would conclude immediately the nonexistence of Reinhardt cardinals. Indeed, more can be said: [Suzuki proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2586799) ([doi: 10.2307/2586799](https://doi.org/10.2307/2586799))that there is no definable-*from-parameters* elementary embedding from $V$ into $V$. This is a harder result: in principle, the relevant parameters might be moved by the embedding, so you don't get the obvious contradiction. *(EDIT: note that Suzuki **did not assume** that $V$ satisfies choice.)*

There is, however, a "first-order version" of Reinhardt cardinals: namely, we look at nontrivial elementary embeddings of $V_{\lambda+2}$ into $V_{\lambda +2}$ for some $\lambda$. These are more-or-less equivalent to Reinhardt cardinals for our purposes here:

- Every Reinhardt cardinal yields such an embedding: if $j:V\rightarrow V$ is nontrivial elementary with critical point $\kappa$, let $$\lambda=\sup_{n\in\omega}(j^{(n)}(\kappa)).$$ Then $j$ restricts to an elementary embedding $\hat{j}:V_{\lambda+2}\rightarrow V_{\lambda+2}$ with critical point $\kappa$.
- Conversely, Kunen's analysis applies to these without changes: assuming ZFC + $\kappa$ is Reinhardt, the crucial combinatorial object in the Kunen inconsistency (namely, the appropriate Jonsson function) exists in $V_{\lambda+2}$. That is, Kunen's argument without substantial changes shows that ZFC proves "There is no nontrivial elementary embedding from $V_{\lambda+2}$ to $V_{\lambda+2}$ for any $\lambda$."
- EDIT: Alessandro Codenotti reminded me in a comment below that there *is* actually a small subtlety here - this is one of those times where the *choice of pairing function* actually matters. You need to use a [flat pairing function](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62801/8133) here. If you use a non-flat pairing function, you wind up getting a weaker result - e.g. at a glance the usual Kuratowski pairing function gives only that there are no nontrivial self-elementary embeddings of $V_{\lambda+\color{red}{4}}$.

Interestingly, the above "localization" suggests a couple weakenings of the Reinhardt principle which turn out to be quite interesting: nontrivial elementary embeddings from $V_{\lambda+1}$ to $V_{\lambda+1}$, or from $V_\lambda$ to $V_\lambda$, for some $\lambda$. These are "small enough" (if just barely) to escape Kunen's argument, and are called $I_1$ and $I_3$ embeddings respectively. There are also other less obvious variations; collectively, these are called [rank-into-rank cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-into-rank).

Comment: A quick note since this confused me when I first learned about rank into rank cardinals: you need to use a flat pairing function to get the Jónsson function in $V_{\lambda+2}$, it won't work with Kuratowski pairs

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Quite right - I've edited that in.