# Is there a first-order sentence defining a cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Being an *ordinal* is first-order definable, within ZFC at least.

Out of many possible first-order characterizations, one is that an ordinal is a transitive set where $\in$ is trichotomous, i.e. $w$ is an ordinal if and only if:

1. $[\forall x]([\exists a](x \in a \land a \in w) \to x \in w)$
2. $[\forall x \forall y](x \in y \lor x = y \lor x \ni y)$

Being a Reinhardt cardinal is [not first-order definable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302925/is-being-a-reinhardt-cardinal-first-order-definable).

However, the much more basic question of whether *being a cardinal* is first-order definable doesn't seem to exist yet.

**Is being a cardinal first-order definable?**

Comment: Really "almost any mathematical construction that doesn't do anything too weird" will be first-order definable in the language of ZFC. The whole point of ZFC is that it formalises set-theoretical constructions. With a statement like "$w$ is a cardinal" it becomes quite clear with experience that there will be no "obstacles" in an attempted formalisation. (At least if you know about things like initial ordinals or Scott's trick). Reinhardt cardinals are really exceptionally weird, because they talk about elementary embeddings of the universe into itself.

Comment: Roughly, so long as your construction uses only set-theoretic principles and only needs to talk about set-sized objects you should expect it to formalise. Many texts on set theory will briefly address this but subsequently take it for granted. Particularly with cardinals, discussion of things like Scott's trick does have the purpose of making sure that "cardinal" is a definable concept. Some discussion of the particular formula does come up in situations where it's important to know eg that "$x$ is a cardinal" is a $\Pi_1^{\text{ZFC}}$ formula for absoluteness reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, here's one way to do it. It's kind of unsatisfying because it isn't succinct like the first-order characterization of an ordinal.

As has been established, being an ordinal is a first-order property.

Two sets having the same cardinality as each other also has a first-order characterization. $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if and only if there exists a bijection between them and a bijection is a set of pairs satisfying some additional first-order condtions.

A cardinal is the least ordinal of a given cardinality. Thus $w$ is a cardinal if and only if:

1. $w$ is an ordinal.
2. For every ordinal $v$ of the same cardinality as $w$, it holds that $v = w$ or $w \in v$.

These two conditions can be expanded into a long first-order formula.